# Using the Group By statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to deploy a table in SSRS by using group by only `Symbol` and `region` and don't want to group by Trade because I am get incorrect results. I've used the following code :

```
SELECT Symbol, Region, Trade, SUM(Profit) AS Total
FROM dbo.[15 Mins]
GROUP BY Symbol 
HAVING SUM(Profit)<0
```

The report says Column 'dbo.15 Mins.Trade' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Well what I want is to group the Negative Sum(Profit) only by the symbols and say when I click the plus sign on the SSRS report, it further drills down and shows the detailed data : Symbol- Region- Trade - Profit of each trade.

Eg.

```
SYMBOL  REGION TRADE PROFIT

Apple   NYSE   BUY   100  
Apple   NYSE   BUY   -200
MSFT    NYSE   BUY   300
MSFT    NYSE   SELL  500
```

so basically what I want in SSRS :

1) get symbols which have a negative sum(profit)

```
SYMBOL  REGION TRADE SUM(Profit)
(+)Apple                -100
```

After I press the (+) sign the table expands and shows me the following :

```
SYMBOL  REGION TRADE SUM(Profit)
Apple   NYSE   BUY   100  
Apple   NYSE   BUY   -200
```

Comment: The general group by rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." This means you have to decide how to treat columns not in the GROUP BY! Remove, aggregate function, or add to group by clause are the alternatives. Also, if you add sample data and wanted result it will be easier for everybody to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @jarlh: Would this suffice ?

Comment: Remove Region and Trade from your select list and you will have the first result. When you press (+), you just want all Apple rows?

Comment: I want Region and Trade in my data as this helps the user to identify his trade. :)  Sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: What if Apple is traded in two regions? Do you want different rows for each region? And do you want trade BUY/SELL in different rows? Or do you just want "empty" columns?

Comment: Thanks Jarlh, I would like to have different rows for each region & want trade BUY/SELL in different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #a
(
    symbol VARCHAR(100),
    region VARCHAR(100),
    trade VARCHAR(100),
    profit int
)

INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('Apple',   'NYSE',   'BUY',   100  );
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('Apple',   'NYSE',   'BUY',   -200);
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('MSFT ',   'NYSE',   'BUY',   300);
INSERT INTO #a VALUES ('MSFT ',   'NYSE',   'SELL', 500);

SELECT a.symbol ,
       a.region ,
       a.trade ,
       a.profit,
       b.profit AS negative_profit
FROM #a a
JOIN (
SELECT b.symbol, SUM(b.profit) profit FROM #a b GROUP BY b.symbol HAVING  SUM(b.profit) < 0
) b
ON  a.symbol = b.symbol
;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sidux, when I run this im getting wrong vales

Comment: There is very good practice to ask the question:
1) Provide sample data;
2) Provide expected results;
3) Provide scripts to generate schema + sample data.

Comment: Thank u so much @Sidux for visualizing and coming up with such a brilliant solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, different rows for different regions, and different rows for buy/sell:

```
SELECT Symbol, Region, Trade, SUM(Profit) AS Total
FROM dbo.[15 Mins]
GROUP BY Symbol, Region, Trade
HAVING SUM(Profit)<0
```

Comment: I did this and I had mentioned that I don't want to group by trade as its giving me wrong values

Comment: Wrong how? You did just say you want different rows for buy/sell... Or you still want the SUM for all Apple rows, on both BUY and SELL rows?

Comment: I tried this before posting it here, the problem was that it showed symbols with both positive and negative Sum(Profit) and gave vague results. I'm very thankful that you've taken the effort to reply to my query. Cheers mate ! :)